# Docker-compose can not sync package.json file via volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, package.json, docker-volume

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  database:
    image: mongo:3.6
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db

  server:
    restart: on-failure
    image: parseplatform/parse-server:5.2.3
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
      - 9229:9229
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=$SERVER_APPLICATION_ID
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_NAME=$SERVER_APPLICATION_NAME
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=$SERVER_MASTER_KEY
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://admin:admin@mongo/parse_server?authSource=admin
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_GRAPHQL=true
      - PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD=/parse-server/cloud/main.js
      - PARSE_SERVER_GRAPH_QLSCHEMA=/parse-server/cloud/schema_2.graphql
    links:
      - database:mongo
    depends_on:
      - database
    entrypoint: "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 /parse-server/bin/parse-server"
    volumes:
      - parse_server_cloud:/parse-server/cloud
      - ./parse-server/package.json:/parse-server/package.json
volumes:
  mongo_data:
  parse_server_cloud:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./parse-server/cloud
      o: bind
```

When I am trying to run it via:

```
docker-compose up -d server
```

I am getting this following error:

> ERROR: for 043a399a1ce9_docker_server_1  Cannot start service server:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: unable to start container process: error during container
> init: error mounting "PRJ_PATH/docker/parse-server/package.json" to
> rootfs at "/parse-server/package.json": mount
> PRJ_PATH/docker/parse-server/package.json:/parse-server/package.json
> (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are
> you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if
> the specified host path exists and is the expected type
>
> ERROR: for server  Cannot start service server: failed to create shim
> task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start
> container process: error during container init: error mounting
> "PRJ_PATH/docker/parse-server/package.json" to rootfs at
> "/parse-server/package.json": mount
> PRJ_PATH/docker/parse-server/package.json:/parse-server/package.json
> (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are
> you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if
> the specified host path exists and is the expected type ERROR:
> Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

the `ls -l` output from docker container:

```
total 648
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            70 Jun 17  2022 bin
drwxrwxrwx    1 node     node           384 Mar 27 07:42 cloud
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Mar 27 06:59 config
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           916 Jun 17  2022 lib
drwxr-xr-x    1 node     node           110 Mar 27 06:59 logs
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7818 Jun 17  2022 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        654393 Jun 17  2022 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6289 Jun 17  2022 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           280 Jun 17  2022 public_html
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            30 Jun 17  2022 views
```

Does dose anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add `ls` to the question so we can understand the file structure?

Comment: I've added the ls output for the docker container, is this what you asked for?